# x11 Remote Desktop with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, x11

When I was running Debian, I was able to start a remote session over x11 by just typing `gnome-session`

However, with Ubuntu 12.04, this only seems to result in my desktop and background being forwarded over x11 -- the top bar (where the clock is) and dock are both missing. I tried starting all of unity by executing `unity`, but that just resulted in a segfault.

How can I start a Unity 2D session over x11?

**Edit:** I prefer x11 as I need to tunnel the connection over 2 other servers. I would need to do a good amount of port forwarding within SSH to get any other connections back. Of course, if someone has any other suggestions, I'm willing to listen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it working with:

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

This will automatically start `unity-2d-panel` and `unity-2d-shell`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this a slightly more forward compatible, I'll add that you can find the sessions in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/. You'll see files like ubuntu-2d.session, gnome-classic.session, etc. You'll then use `gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d`. In other words, you'll just drop the ".session" from the name.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on an `esxi-server`. With ubuntu-2d session it doesn't work. So I have defined in `.xsession` file `gnome-session --session=gnome-classic`.

Be sure the file `gnome-classic.session` exist in `/usr/gnome-session/sessions`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one solution is just to install `gnome-classic` and use that:

Install `gnome-panel`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Start gnome-fallback session:

```
gnome-session-fallback
```

It works, it's fast, quick, and functional. I would still be curious about Ubuntu 2D, although I prefer classic anyways.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: did you try with `gnome-session --session=ubuntu2d` (that should also call `unity-2d-panel` if installed)

Comment: @Takkat I had not -- but just did. A little box appears which says "Failed to load session 'ubuntu2d'" in my x11 session. If you want a screenshot let me know. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's called ubuntu-2d, not ubuntu2d.