# How to use X11?

Tags: xorg, android, 17.04, gui

I'm currently playing a bit with X11.

1. I tried to display something from my Ubuntu PC on my Android tablet. 
   I installed and Xorg server in Android, set `DISPLAY=<address>` on the PC and ran `xclock`: this worked, the clock appeared in Android. If I run `metacity & gimp`, I get the GIMP GUI in the android machine. Is there a chance to get the Ubuntu desktop in Android?
2. I wanted to run an X program in amazon EC2 Ubuntu and display the output on my local PC. Therefore I installed LXDE on the EC2 machine. But neither `lxdm` nor `gnome-session` work. Nothing happens.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157429/x11-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-12-04 looks like a solution to #1, but it does not work. Running gnome-session, nothing happens. Really nothing.

Comment: Once you enable X forwading you just run your application. If "it does not work" you need to post your ssh configuration, the ssh command you ran, the graphical command you ran, and the error message. Typically you do not need to export the display variable and typically the default disoplay is :10

Comment: You can't run an entire gnome-session over the tunnel. You would just run the individual applications. What eaxactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @dobey - You can forward an entire desktop, use Xephyr . See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=620003 and https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/xephyr.html . For other options see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7226/launch-a-gnome-session-from-terminal

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That is forwarding a separate X server, which is itself hosting a session. Might as well just set up VNC at that point, as it would be much faster.

Comment: @dobey FreeNX is IMO fastest VNC server. At any rate just pointing out it is possible. Xephyr is fast enough if you ssh into a chroot or LXC from the host or over a LAN. Slow over the internet.

Comment: Please split up your questions to avoid having this closed as too broad. As written this question would require someon to have expertise in both android and amazon EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

For access from ubuntu pc to amazon ec2 ubuntu machine:

- install remmina on local pc
- install lxde and xrdp on remote machine (sudo apt install ...)
- ssh to remote machine with .pem file and set password: sudo passwd ubuntu (rdp wants password)
- start remmina on local pc, configure for rdp to ip-adresse of amazon ec2,    resolution local width*local height-64px   color depth 16bit, enable    ssh-tunnel, tunnel via loopback, same server port 22, identity file amazon-ec2.pem (as downloaded from amazon)
- click "connect" in the remmina configuration window
- you should get login screen from xrdp. select module sesman-Xvnc,    user ubuntu and password from above.
- now you should get a lxdm desktop

(this should also work directly with x11 without rdp, but I did not find out how to do it)