# How can I display whole Ubuntu XWindow desktop on my Windows PC screen, with Xming

Tags: xserver

As title, I tried command

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

from my PuTTY console, but after some seconds, it fails saying something like:

```
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[14452]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session[14452]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

What's going wrong?

**====== Flashback ======**

I have to PCs, A running Windows and Xming, B running Ubuntu 14.04 .

According to tutorial http://www.nth-design.com/2010/05/19/x11-putty-xming/ , I have successfully tell B machines's `/usr/bin/firefox` to display its window on A's side.

And, according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157429/x11-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-12-04), I guess that `gnome-session` can be used to display the whole Ubuntu graphical desktop on A's side, but no luck yet. So please help, or, if it is not an easy task, I'd like to know what is the blocking factor.

[image]